# Emacs commands to calculate sum, average, etc. of region

Tags: emacs

Suppose I have highlighted a region of text in a buffer. The region contains numbers separated by whitespace. E.g.

```
1 19 23 28 41
```

Is there some package with ready-made interactive commands that parse the numbers from this region and do common calculations like sum and average, similar to what spreadsheet programs show in their status bar? Something like:

- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `sum-region` => `112` shown in minibuffer
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `average-region` => `22.4` shown in minibuffer

or a combined command to do different calculations at once, or a modeline display.

I suppose `org-mode` has spreadsheet functions like this, but can they be used easily if you're not already working with an org spreadsheet? Does `calc` have functions that operate on region?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found one pretty easy way using `calc`:

1. Highlight the numbers in the source buffer
2. <kbd>M-x</kbd> `calc-grab-region` (or <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>*</kbd> <kbd>g</kbd>)
3. <kbd>M-x</kbd> `calc-vector-sum`, <kbd>M-x</kbd> `calc-vector-mean`, <kbd>M-x</kbd> `calc-vector-sdev`, etc.

<kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>*</kbd> is a prefix sequence that invokes Calc in a number of ways; the letter that follows determines which one (e.g. <kbd>g</kbd> invokes `calc-grab-region`, <kbd>r</kbd> invokes `calc-grab-rectangle`).

Statistical functions can also be invoked by key sequences. For example:

- <kbd>u</kbd><kbd>+</kbd>: sum (`calc-vector-sum`)
- <kbd>u</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>: covariance (`calc-vector-covariance`)
- <kbd>u</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>: mean (`calc-vector-mean`)
- <kbd>u</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>: standard deviation (`calc-vector-sdev`)
- <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>+</kbd>: sum (`(calc-reduce '(2 calcFunc-add "+"))`)
- <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>*</kbd>: product (`(calc-reduce '(2 calcFunc-mul "*"))`)

These and other functions are covered in the [Calc manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/), particularly the section on [Vector/Matrix Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Matrix-Functions.html#Matrix-Functions).

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest an easy way to calculate the sum, by using Emacs Lisp,

```
(+ 1 19 23 28 41)
```

Then C-x C-e to evaluate, and the value will be there in the echo area.